# Facebook spamming user@facebook.com email sent from server

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

We are developing a mobile application that communicates with a server, which sends a generated email on behalf of the app user to a facebook user.

- The user sending the email is signed on to Facebook.
- The email is sent to one or multiple FB friends/connection using their id (example: username@facebook.com).
- The sender email can be from any domain and that's where the problem lies. Sending directly from gmail for example, works fine. But because our server is sending on behalf of the user, FB thinks its a spoofed email.
- Sending the email from the app is not an option for us at this time.

Is there any way or service that would allow us to do this without having our emails marked as spam?

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook is transitioning away from the ability to send emails via an
>   API call on Mar. 1st. To compensate, they allow apps to now ask for a
>   user's email address directly.
>
> If you set the email domain in your app's settings, then asking for
>   the email extended permission gives you the users email address
>   instead the ability to send an email via the API.
>
> As of Mar. 1, the API will stop working and you are left alone to
>   figure out your own email solution. This goes for regular
>   notifications, both user to user and app to user, as well

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339056/having-difficulties-with-notifications-sendemail-from-the-facebook-api-using-php)

And:

```
Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, 
and will not be adding support for this in Graph API. 
Developers should directly send email to users once they are granted permission.
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825065/sending-email-notification-via-graph-api-facebook)

However, I would suggest rather sending private message than emails, as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Comment: We are not using FB's API to send email. We are using our own SMTP server to send emails on behalf of the user. Sending private message is a problematic for us because we need to send customized email to multiple recipients.